# Value cannot be null. Parameter name: httpBrowserCapabilities

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I just created a new MVC application from VS 2015. Target framework is **.NET 4.5**.

In the first debug, it shows

> Value cannot be null.
>
> Parameter name: httpBrowserCapabilities
>
> **Exception Details:** System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>
> Parameter name: httpBrowserCapabilities

And the stacktrace points to: `System.Web.HttpBrowserCapabilitiesWrapper..ctor(HttpBrowserCapabilities httpBrowserCapabilities) +3511141`.

[image: error message]

What could be wrong here? I reinstalled Visual Studio yesterday but it still won't fix. What can possibly break this `httpBrowserCapabilities`?

---

Reinstalled my Visual Studio, no fix.

The whole situation looks like what is described in these posts:

- [Webmatrix and iis 8. Default project doesn't not work](http://forums.asp.net/t/1960701.aspx?Webmatrix%20and%20iis%208%20Default%20project%20doesn%20t%20not%20work)
- [Webmatrix only error with ajaxtoolkit](http://forums.asp.net/t/1960670.aspx?Webmatrix%20only%20error%20with%20ajaxtoolkit).

It just happened suddenly and there is just no way to fix!

Comment: What are you doing that requires `httpBrowserCapabilities`? As of right now, this looks like a common `NullReferenceException`, but with an argument to a constructor.

Comment: That's the most confusing part. I have done nothing. It is a fresh application created by the MVC template.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like some code somewhere is trying to use `HttpBrowserCapabilities` to do browser detection. Weird thing is that MVC does not use this at all, and in fact, the only usage of it I can find is in conjunction with Web Forms server controls. If this is truly just a scaffolded project, without any additions by you, then it's possible you chose the wrong project type (though I have no idea why *any* built-in project scaffold would throw exceptions by default).

Regardless, my best advice is to simply create a new solution, and make sure you choose "ASP.NET Web Application" as your project type.

Answer (score 0):

This is only a makeshift.

I find I could use **Local IIS** instead of **IIS Express** to run the web applications.

So it appears something is wrong with the **IIS Express**. But a re-installation of Visual Studio won't fix it. Neither could a re-installation of .NET framework do.

Anyway, since I have a local IIS, I just change the **Servers** properties in the application's **Properties**, **Web** tab. Have to run Visual Studio **as Administrator**. And check **Override application root URL**.

So now I am back in working mode. I will look into how to fix IIS express later. If anyone has a better solution, please share with us. Thanks.